# Custom OrderBy for IList

Tags: c#

**I have an** `IList<string>` **and want to order by this list based on the following scenario:**
The elements which start with "abs" stay at top and the others will be sorted in the normal way as `String.CompareTo`

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 2):

Tty this simple code:

`stringArray.OrderBy(x => x.StartsWith("abs") ? 0: 1).ThenBy(x => x);`

Answer (score 1):

You should implement your custom IComparer and use the Sort method of the list.

`List<T>.Sort Method (IComparer<T>)`

[Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

try to implement custom Comparator

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    strings.add("abs");
    strings.add("a");
    strings.add("b");
    strings.add("bb");
    strings.add("ac");
    strings.add("c");
    Collections.sort(strings, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            if (o1.equalsIgnoreCase("abs")) {
                return -1;
            } else if (o2.equalsIgnoreCase("abs")) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
        }
    });
```

**Update** I thought this was `Java` before tag was changed. don't know if above code helps

Answer (score 0):

```
var abs = list.Where(e = e.StartsWith("abs")).OrderBy(e => e);
var rest = list.Except(abs).OrderBy(e => e);

var result = abs.Concat(rest);
```